# How to add an hour onto the time of this datetime string?

Tags: php

Here's an example of the datetime strings I am working with:

```
Tue May 15 10:14:30 +0000 2012
```

Here is my attempt to add an hour onto it:

```
$time = 'Tue May 15 10:14:30 +0000 2012';
$dt = new DateTime($time);
$dt->add(new DateInterval('P1h'));
```

But the second line gives the error that it couldn't be converted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You should add a `T` before the time specification part:

```
$time = 'Tue May 15 10:14:30 +0000 2012';
$dt = new DateTime($time);
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
```

See the `DateInterval` [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) documentation:

> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. *If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is **preceded by the letter T***.

<sub>(Emphasis added)</sub>

Answer (score 29):

Previous answers works fine. However, I usually use datetime modify in my externally hosted websites. Check [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) for more information.
With the code proposed, it should work like this:

```
$time = 'Tue May 15 10:14:30 +0000 2012';
$dt = new DateTime($time);
$dt->modify('+ 1 hour');
```

For those not using object orientation, just use it this way (first line DateTime just to bring somethng new to this thread, I use it to check server time):

```
$dt = new DateTime("@".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);  // convert UNIX epoch to PHP DateTime
$dt = date_modify($dt, "+1 hour");
```

Best,

Answer (score 9):

Using **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**:

```
$time = 'Tue May 15 10:14:30 +0000 2012';
$time = strtotime($time) + 3600; // Add 1 hour
$time = date('D M j G:i:s O Y', $time); // Back to string
echo $time;
```